# Is there a natural topology on the automorphism group of a topological group?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, automorphism-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\TAut{TAut}\DeclareMathOperator\Homeo{Homeo}$Let $G$ be a topological group, and let $\TAut(G)$ denote the group of topological automorphisms of $G$ under composition (i.e. the group of maps $f \colon G \to G$ that are simultaneously group automorphisms and self-homeomorphisms).

We wish to give $\TAut(G)$ a reasonable topology in the following sense:

1. $\TAut(G)$ becomes a topological group with respect to this topology.
2. This topology should interact with/depend on the topology of $G$ in some way, i.e. we can require that the natural action $\TAut(G) \times G \to G$ is continuous.

In the case that $G$ is compact, it is known that giving $\TAut(G)$ the compact–open topology satisfies the above conditions, where the compact–open topology has as a subbasis sets of the form $$V(C, U) = \{f \colon G \to G \mid f(C) \subseteq U\},$$ where $C, U \subseteq G$ are compact and open, respectively.

If $G$ is locally compact, we can instead give $\TAut(G)$ the $g$-topology, which has as a subbasis sets of the form $$V(K, W) = \{f \colon G \to G \mid f(K) \subseteq W\},$$ where either $K$ or $G \setminus W$ is compact.

The cases where $G$ is compact or locally compact are discussed in [Dijkstra - On Homeomorphism Groups and the
Compact–Open Topology](https://www.cs.vu.nl/%7Edijkstra/research/papers/2005compactopen.pdf) and [Arens - Topologies for Homeomorphism Groups](https://doi.org/10.2307/2371787). In fact, these two papers discuss the group of self-homeomorphisms $\Homeo(X)$ for a space $X$ which is not necessarily a topological group, so the case for $G$ and $\TAut(G)$ follows from that (since $\TAut(G)$ is a subgroup of $\Homeo(G)$).

My question is, for a general topological group $G$, is there a good way to describe a topology on $\TAut(G)$ satisfying the two conditions above? We can simply say: "give $\TAut(G)$ the coarsest topology such that it becomes a topological group and the action $\TAut(G) \times G \to G$ is continuous," but I am hoping for something more explicit than that.

Comment: It seems (and you say it) that all this only depends on the topology on $G$, so this is a discussion about the topology on homeomorphism group of spaces. (And then for a topological group, you then restrict the topology to the group of self-homeomorphisms preserving the group structure.)

Comment: @YCor My hope is that we can leverage the group-theoretic relations between $G$ and $\text{TAut}(G)$ to say more about $\text{TAut}(G)$ than we could by considering $\text{Homeo}(G)$ and then restricting. In addition to its structure as a subgroup of $\text{Homeo}(G),$ $\text{TAut}(G)$ also has structure from being a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$ (the group automorphisms of $G$). I am wondering if this would allow us to work with $\text{TAut}(G)$ even when $\text{Homeo}(G)$ does not necessarily have a nice topology on it.

Comment: What about the topology that TAut$(G)$ inherits from Homoe$(\alpha G)$, where $\alpha G$ is the one-point compactification?

Comment: @Echo Thank you! I need to write out some more details, but this looks promising.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$There is a recent paper [Uniformly locally bounded spaces and the group of automorphisms of a topological group](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.00548) by Maxime Gheysens where he among other nice things systematically investigates the topologies on $\Aut(G)$ for any topological group $G$. On every topological group there are several natural uniform structures making translations become uniformly continuous: first of all, the left and right uniform structure, their supremum  (the upper uniform structure) and their infimum (the lower or Roelcke uniform structure). Now, as it turns out, on $\Aut(G)$ one can usefully consider:

- the topology of uniform biconvergence on bounded sets with respect to the left, right, or upper uniform structure (they all give the same topology) or
- the topology of uniform biconvergence on bounded sets with respect to the lower uniform structure.

In general, these two topologies are different, but they coincide for the so-called SIN groups (and even broader, for coarsely SIN groups), i.e. groups with admitting a basis of conjugation-invariant identity neighborhoods as well as for all locally compact groups. So the existence of two really different useful topologies on $\Aut(G)$ is purely a phenomenon in the world of “very big” groups.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.